# Program isn't logging user input to console upon form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I would like to know how I can make the program log the input values from the user to the console after the user clicks the "Sign up now" button.

Comment: A form has an onsubmit method, not a button

Comment: `onsubmit="myFunction()"` this should be on your form tag.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `button` elements do not raise a `submit` event.

That aside, you shouldn't be using the outdated `on*` event attributes anyway. Use unobtrusive event handlers, which you can attach using `addEventListener()`, like this:

```js
function logOptions() {
  var s = document.getElementsByName('Interests')[0];
  var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(text);
}

function logEmail() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
}

document.getElementById('inputform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  logOptions();
  logEmail();
});
```

```html
<h2>Stay up to date with ecommerce trends <br>with Shopify's newsletter</h2>
<h4>Subscribe for free marketing tips</h4>

<form id="inputform" method="get" action="confirmation.html">
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
  <button type="submit" id="validate">Sign up now</button>
  <select name="Interests" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Interested in..</option>
    <option value="option1">Marketing</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option4</option>
  </select>
</form>

<svg>
  <rect width="40" height="3" style="fill: lightgreen" />
</svg>
```

Also note that I added the call to `preventDefault()`. This is just for testing so that you can see the result of the `console.log()` call. You can remove this in your production code when you actually want the form submission to complete.

Comment: I also want it to redirect to the "confirmation.html" page once the button is clicked

Comment: Then remove the `e.preventDefault()` call that I noted in the question.

Comment: I have but it still won't log the values to the console using your code. It says in the console "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null'

Comment: It does, but it just submits the form too quickly for you to see it. Did you read the last paragraph of my answer at all?

Comment: I did see your last paragraph what I am trying to say is that it does not log the values even when I have the preventDefault() in my code because it gives me a Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error.

Comment: In that case you either have no `inputform` element in the DOM, or are running your JS code too early. Try moving the `<script>` tag to just before the `</body>`

Comment: So you are saying that I should move what is inside <script> </script> towards the end of the </body> tag

Comment: Not just the contents of the `<script>`, but the entire tag itself.

Comment: Do you know what I would have to do to make the entire webpage responsive?

Comment: You can use CSS Media Queries for that

Comment: So I would have to apply those to each element in my css code that is being styled right?

Comment: Well, at least each element you want to amend as the screen size is changed. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped